# Disable Vimperator ecape passthrough in Facebook chat

Tags: vimperator

When using the Facebook chat and Vimperator, when I push escape to leave insert mode, the chat window also exits. Is there any way to stop Vimperator from letting Facebook see the key press?

Comment: I just installed Vimperator and so far this is only downside for me...

Comment: Not really a solution, but you can try clicking outside the chat window to leave INSERT mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can map jj to escape insert mode by add this line to .vimperatorrc

```
imap jj <Esc>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following greasemonkey script to disable the shortcut:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        fb_esc_disable
// @namespace   Olm
// @description FB Chat ESC shortcut remover
// @include     /^https?://www\.facebook\.com/.*$/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
unsafeWindow.document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    // 27 = ESC
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return;
  }
}, true);
})();
```